# Second display does not work

Tags: monitor, gpu-driver

I am kind of new to Ubuntu.
I have an i7-7700 with z270 motherboard and hd630 graphics. I have 2 LG 24mp68vq displays. I have connected one of them with a VGA cable and when I try to connect the second one with HDMI, neither of them shows any picture.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check if the monitors are recognized by your system. To do this, go in System Settings and click on Display icon. Second, if you didn't, check your driver configuration in additional drivers, if possible check the proprietary driver and install it.